# Jw player not working in android & IOS devices

Tags: android, mobile, jwplayer, wowza, mobile-browser

JWPlayer which is integrated in web browser(website) is working fine on all desktop browser where as coming to mobile it is not working and also showing that "Error loading media: File could not be played" can any one help me in fixation of this,Here I am attaching concern code thanks in advance.

```
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, handheld" href="style.css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js" ></script> 
    <script>jwplayer.key="UqsxqSzE4fs4e3/+JJ4g2zVO2jxpFkwT31IzfQ=="</script> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <input type="text" id="stream" value="rtmp://192.168.2.108:1935/live/test.stream"></input> 
    <button id="start">Start</button>
    <button id="stop">Stop</button>
    <div id="status"></div>
  </body>
</html>`
```

Comment: Please give us a link to your site. We aren't psychics. But it's always the same advice: run the video through Handbrake with default settings, plus check "Web optimized." If the resulting video works, you have an encoding problem.

http://handbrake.fr/

Comment: You need to provide a link.

Comment: @MisterNeutron : Agreed with u . He should check the encoding first

Comment: what is your video format? can you provide some more information, if you can not provide link at least provide some code so that we can find the issue

Comment: Hi friends i just updated my source code please go through it once

Comment: @hitesh My video format is .mp4